# How can you loop through a mysql_fetch_array() with a for loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I am doing a MySQL `SELECT` on my database with PHP and I want to loop through the results. I am using `mysql_fetch_array()` to do this. I was originally using a `while` loop to loop through the results the problem I encountered is that in the loop I need to get what row the loop is currently in. I thought a for loop would do this because then I would have $i to get the value of the problem is that I do not think it will work. Below is my code. Is it possible to do what I am asking and am I doing it the right way?

```
$q = "SELECT test_id, title, subject, type, creation_date FROM tests WHERE user_id='$user_id' LIMIT 10"; //select first ten of users tests
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0) {//if the query ran correctly and the test details were gathered from the database

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)

for($i=1; i<10; i++) {

$test_id = $row['test_id'];
$test_type = $row['type'];
$creation_date = $row['creation_date'];
$creator = $user_id;
$title = $row['title'];
$subject = $row['subject'];

$q = "SELECT tag_id FROM test_tags WHERE test_id='$test_id[$i]"; //select tags corresponding to this test
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `while` loop like you did before and just keep a variable `$i` which is incremented once per iteration.

```
$q = "SELECT test_id, title, subject, type, creation_date FROM tests WHERE user_id='$user_id' LIMIT 10"; //select first ten of users tests
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0) {//if the query ran correctly and the test details were gathered from the database

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
    $i = 0;

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
        $test_id = $row['test_id'];
        $test_type = $row['type'];
        $creation_date = $row['creation_date'];
        $creator = $user_id;
        $title = $row['title'];
        $subject = $row['subject'];

        $q = "SELECT tag_id FROM test_tags WHERE test_id='$test_id[$i]"; //select tags corresponding to this test
        $r2 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        $i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a fetching line of code before the loop that does the same action?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `foreach()` construction to loop through the result object. Something like this:

```
//select first ten of users tests
$q = "SELECT test_id, title, subject, type, creation_date FROM tests WHERE user_id='$user_id' LIMIT 10"; 
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$i = 0;
//loop through result object:
foreach ($r as $row) {
  $row[$i]['test_id'] = $test_id;
  //...

  $q = "SELECT tag_id FROM test_tags WHERE test_id='$test_id[$i]"; //select tags corresponding to this test
  $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

  //loop through the new result:

  foreach ($r as $tag) {
    $tags[] = $tag;
  }

  $i++; //increment counter.

  //Not sure where you're going from here, but...

  $row[$i]['tags'] = $tag; //add tags array to $row
  return $row[$i];
}
```