# How to do for loop when accessing each row returned by mysql_fetch_object?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
function x(){
   ....blablabla.. 
return mysql_fetch_object($result);
}
$entries = x();

foreach($entries as $entry){
echo "$entry->member_1";
```

}

when i did this, it gave me 0 result and printed nothing on the screen. I have seen the while-loop solutions too many times already, I want to know if there is a way to do this using for loop? thx

Comment: mysql_fetch_object gets 1 row from the query, not all rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you loop through a mysql_fetch_array() with a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690015/how-can-you-loop-through-a-mysql-fetch-array-with-a-for-loop)

Comment: James is right. You need to do `while($entry = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { ... }`.

Comment: @ Ted Hopp: I want to see a for loop solution in this case. I knew that while loop would have solved this problem right away..

Comment: @James: Right. now i know why everybody prefers while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either want:

```
function x(){
   ....blablabla..
   $return = array();
   while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result)) $return[] = $object;
   return $return;
}

$entries = x();
foreach($entries as $entry){
   echo $entry->member_1;
}
```

Or:

```
function x(){
   ....blablabla.. 
   return mysql_fetch_object($result);
}
$entries = x();

foreach(get_object_vars($entries) as $entry){
   echo $entry->member_1;
}
```

I suspect the first.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$result = mysql_query(..);
for (;$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);) {
    echo $row->member_1;
}
```